# IMG tag is not wirking properly on XAMPP and on regular html file

Tags: html

Friend of mine started to learn html/css and asked me super easy question why his

```
<img src="file.jpg"/>
```

is not working.
I have installed XAMPP and I have just created simple  tag and it wasn't working for me also.
I'm 100% sure is not path related problem because I have created index.html file with code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>

<img scr="kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr=".kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="..kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="/kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="./kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="../kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="//kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr=".//kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="..//kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr=".\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="..\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="\\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr=".\\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="..\\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="C:\Users\Public\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="C:\\Users\\Public\\kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="file:///C:/Users/Public/kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="file://C:/Users/Public/kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="file:/C:/Users/Public/kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="C:/Users/Public/kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />
<img scr="C://Users//Public//kurde.jpg" alt="Witam" />

</body>
</html>
```

index.html is in the same directory as kurde.jpg and all permission on windows are just normal so everybody can read the file. But the file generate only ALT text on website. Same situation is happening on XAMPP server. When I try to access file through web browser it showing me picture correctly.

I have read many threads and most of them were about wrong paths but I understan relative/absolute path correctly and it is not the case.

Comment: `src` != `scr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo mistake in html document
The attribute is src instead of scr.

Comment: OMG i cant handle this. I need to delete my account. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend, you should use good editor like vs code which will take care of the typos.

Answer (score -1):

Use an absolute path of the image if it's stored inside a web server.

```
file:///C:/Users/Public/kurde.jp
```

Would works in a directory folder.

Comment: If you serve HTML through a web server, hard-coding local file system paths from your own PC basically prevents everybody else from seeing the pictures.